# How to show applied filters in a View?

Tags: 7, views

I have defined some contextual filters to a View, i need to show a string like "Applied filters: filter_name1:xyz, filter_name2:ykx".
Which is the cleanest way to do it in Views3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to implement a [template_preprocess_views_view](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/theme%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_views_view/7).  The view object is available as `$variables['view']`.  `kpr` this to find the property that has the filters in it.  Process them into something readable.  Then set a new entry in `$variables`.

Then make a new views-view.tpl.php, and name it appropriately for your view (edit the view, click Theme: Information to see the template suggestions), and add the `print` statements to output the filter info.